# I'm trying to make a clock for a website, the time detection works but I'm trying to figure out a way to make it loop (html + js)

Tags: javascript, clock

I considered using an infinite for loop and immediately said nope not gonna work
here's the program, it's pretty big because I wanted each number to be set individually. there are also some `<div>` elements that display the time. if you want me to add them I will

```
var d = new Date();
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var week = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var days = ["", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "14th", "15th", "16th", "17th", "18th", "19th", "20th", "21st", "22nd", "23rd", "24th", "25th", "26th", "27th", "28th", "29th", "30th", "31st"];
    var hourAP = ["12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"];
    var minBegin = ["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"];
    var month = months[d.getMonth()];
    var weekDay = week[d.getDay()];
    var day = days[d.getDate()];
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var date = weekDay + ", " + month + " " + day + ", " + year;
    var hour = hourAP[d.getHours()];
    var minute = minBegin[d.getMinutes()];
    var timeAP;
    if (hour < 12) {
        timeAP = "AM";
    } else {
        timeAP = "PM";
    }
    var time = hour + ":" + minute + " " + timeAP;
    document.getElementById("dateResult").innerHTML = date;
    document.getElementById("timeResult").innerHTML = time;
```

Comment: Could you paste your code

Comment: at a minimum, you need to move your code into your question.

Comment: You could try using [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Comment: Please don't show an image of your code, actually paste it into your question and format it as code using the {} button. Or create a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setInterval() to do something over and over. Here I've used it to run every second (the second parameter of the function is in milliseconds, so one second = 1000)

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var week = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var days = ["", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "14th", "15th", "16th", "17th", "18th", "19th", "20th", "21st", "22nd", "23rd", "24th", "25th", "26th", "27th", "28th", "29th", "30th", "31st"];
var hourAP = ["12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"];
var minBegin = ["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"];


function doTime() {
  // all your code

  var d = new Date();
  var month = months[d.getMonth()];
  var weekDay = week[d.getDay()];
  var day = days[d.getDate()];
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var date = weekDay + ", " + month + " " + day + ", " + year;
  var hour = hourAP[d.getHours()];
  var minute = minBegin[d.getMinutes()];

  // an easier way
  minute = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes()


  var second = d.getSeconds();
  var timeAP;
  if (hour < 12) {
    timeAP = "AM";
  } else {
    timeAP = "PM";
  }
  var time = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + timeAP;
  document.getElementById("dateResult").innerHTML = date;
  document.getElementById("timeResult").innerHTML = time;

}

const timeInterval = setInterval(() => doTime(), 1000);


// if you want to cancel this infinitely repeating function, call clearInterval() 
// clearInterval(timeInterval)
```

```html
<div>
  Date: <span id='dateResult'></span>
</div>
<div>
  Time: <span id='timeResult'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, so 1 second is 1000, 1 minute is (60 * 1000)

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working, it just loads the time then stops. it won't put anything in the console either, even though it works just fine when I run the code snippet here

Comment: If you copy and paste your code into your question, I'll go ahead and insert it into this snippet for demo

Comment: looks good, the snippet works. let's see if it works In my program

Comment: It's running. I added in the seconds, so you could actually see it without waiting for the minute to click over.

Comment: @aperson - Great - please accept as the answer. Also, you can get minutes easier without that array: `var minute = (d.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + d.getMinutes()`